# Why does my progress tag is not working on iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, progress-bar

I have been through this [website](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/) which has tutorial about HTML5 progress tag. The website's progress bar is working fine when I'm viewing the website via the iPad and PC's web browsers but when I created my own html which has only progress tag in body section, it's not working My progress bar code is exactly the same with the one in the website which is

```
<progress max="100" value="60">
     <strong>Progress: 60% done.</strong>
</progress>
```

In my html it's showing "Progress: 60% done." Not any progress bar comes up.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Since it's short, could you post your entire html file so the problem is possible to repeat locally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work: [can I use...progress/meter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter). It's not supported.